# Qual è il significato di "presi in una puntata appena" in questo brano?

Tags: meaning

Nel libro *Racconto d'autunno*, di Tommaso Landolfi, ho letto:

> Ma essi, che in tempi precedenti avevano avuto a subire gravi torti, nel loro paese medesimo, dai nostri connazionali, giungevano
>   ora qui colla sete della vendetta e l'animo dei saccheggiatori e degli stupratori, né, ebbri di conquista, si brigavano di distinzioni
>   purchessia fra amici e nemici, armati e non. Avevano in quel torno infranto alcune difese dei nostri invasori e s'erano affondati fino a noi in territorio avverso; salvoché non poterono a lungo
>   mantenere il nuovo schieramento e furono costretti, fino alla generale avanzata, a retrocedere. Ci trovammo dunque **presi in una
>   puntata appena**, di cui tuttavia avemmo il tempo di sentire gli effetti. Questa che mi circondava era una delle bande di 
>   depredatori che si dilungavano, non poco spesso, dai loro quartieri.

Ho pensato che "puntata" in questo testo avesse questo significato che ho trovato nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/puntata1)

> Assalto, incursione di truppe: *fare una p. offensiva*, un’incursione in un punto avanzato del fronte

ma non sono sicura che questo sia il senso perché la presenza di questo "appena" mi sembra strana. Potreste spiegarmi qual è il significato della frase "Ci trovammo dunque presi in una
puntata appena" nel testo sopra citato?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il significato di puntata nel contesto da te citato è appunto quello che hai trovato tu, cioè assalto, incursione di truppe.

Il senso della frase è che nonostante gli invasori avessero attaccato solamente (appena) una volta gli effetti si erano fatti sentire.

Answer (score 0):

- presi : coinvolti, ingaggiati
- puntata : breve assalto, rapida incursione
- appena : semplicemente

per cui "Ci trovammo dunque presi in una puntata appena" è da intendersi "Ci trovammo dunque coinvolti in una semplice incursione"